# Publish single item dynamically with Subscriber that has timeout

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Currently we have two separate API endpoints.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> get(ServerRequest request) {
  Sinks.StandaloneMonoSink<String> sink = Sinks.promise();
  sinkMap.putIfAbsent(randomID, sink);
  return sink.asMono().timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                      .flatMap(val -> ServerResponse.ok().body(BodyInserters.fromValue(val)))
}

public Mono<ServerResponse> push(ServerRequest request) {
  Sinks.StandaloneMonoSink<String> sink = sinkMap.remove(randomID);
  if (sink == null) {
    return ServerResponse.notFound().build(); }
  else {
    return request.bodyToMono(String.class)
                   .flatMap(data -> {
                       sink.success(data);
                       return ServerResponse().ok().build();
                   }
   }
}
```

The intention is for client to do a `get` request and to keep the connection open for 1 min or so waiting for some data to arrive.  And then on `push` request data will be published to the open connection for `get` and the connection will close upon receipt of first element.

The issue with current approach is that the data may be emitted after `get` request times out and subscription is canceled, thus losing the data.  Is it possible if no subscribers then if I try to emit item throw error or perform another action with data (from the `push` request side).

Thanks.

Comment: How are you using the two methods? Can you please post that too?

Comment: There just api routes.  The routes would be accessed by curling, GET endpoint /get and POST endpoint /push.

Answer (score 0):

I had to read this question multiple times to understand what you are looking for!

---

I tried something like this and it seems to work.

```
private final DirectProcessor<String> processor = DirectProcessor.create();
private final FluxSink<String> sink = processor.sink();


// processor has a method to check if there are any active subscribers.
// if it is true, lets push data, otherwise we can throw exception / store it somehwere
@GetMapping("/push/{val}")
public boolean push(@PathVariable String val){
    boolean status = processor.hasDownstreams();
    if(status)
        sink.next(val);
    return status;
}


@GetMapping("/get")
public Mono<String> get(){
    return processor
            .next()
            .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1));
}
```

---

Question:

- Will you be running only one instance of this application? What will happen when you run multiple instances of this application?

For ex: User A might push the data to app-instance-1 and User B might subscribe to app-instance-2. In this case, User B might not get data. In this case, you might need something like `Redis` to store this data and share among all the instances for pub/sub behavior.

Comment: But this solution wouldn't be able to handle the following edge case:  When User A calls the api to get data and user B calls the api to push data, they will operate on separate threads right. So what happens if `processor.hasDownstreams()` returns true but before it calls next `/get` timeouts.   Then that data item sent to the sink by `/push` is lost.  This seems like a real case possibility.

Comment: Your controllers are singleton. Processors/Sinks are instance variables of the singleton class. So any thread can push and any other thread can receive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  How would that prevent the above scenario.  If downstream unsubscribes due to timeout, and the `status` variable was already evaluated to true, the sink would still push the item even after the downstream unsubscribes.  Instead we would want to perform another action say write to redis cache.  But we can't guarantee order here.  The threads can switch back and forth.  Am I missing something?